# Wrap include around views

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a common LinearLayout that I want to put into its own layout file. It will be used to wrap around different views in different layout files. Is it somehow possible to wrap an include (or achieve a similar effect) around Views?

Comment: What exactly is different about your LinearLayout? Is it just styled a certain way?

Comment: @Karakuri The main thing is that I want to have a custom layout in its own file, and then use that to wrap around different views, but it does not seem possible with include.

Comment: I don't think there is a `wrap` functionality for re-using parent layouts.

Comment: @Raghunandan I don't see how either of those links help me.

Comment: @btse: Yes, that's why I asked. If you just have a normal LinearLayout to which you've applied some style attributes, you should just make a Style reference to use in all your layouts. If it's something more complicated, perhaps you can write a custom component (that extends LinearLayout) and use that in your layouts.

Comment: @Karakuri Doh, idk why I didn't think of using a Style. That's the best solution so if you want to post it as an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 1):

`I have a common LinearLayout that I want to put into its own layout file`

Place the `LinearLayout` in a separate layout file. Inflate this layout file:

```
View mLinearLayoutView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.linear_layout, null);

LinearLayout ll = (LinearLayout) mLinearLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.my_linear_layout);

// Inflate the view you want to include within the LinearLayout
View mChildView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.any_other_child_view, null);

// Initialize/setup any child components   

ll.addView(mChildView);     // Or, ll.addView(mChildView, optional_layout_parameters);

setContentView(mLinearLayoutView);
```